# Mocking a faulted Execute Multiple Response

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, dynamics-365

I'm using [Moq](https://github.com/moq) to unit test my Dynamics 365 plugin development.

My question is... How can I mock a "faulted" [ExecuteMultiResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.executemultipleresponse.aspx)?

Comment: You can't. It is sealed. You can however still create an instance of the class and use it in the test.

Comment: I would recommend that you take a look at [XrmMockup](https://github.com/delegateas/XrmMockup) or [Fake Xrm Easy](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy) for testing D365 plugins.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I mock a "faulted" ExecuteMultiResponse?

You can't. It is `sealed` and thus can't be derived from to create mocks or stubs.

You can however still create an instance of the class and use it in the test

```
//Arrange
var response = new ExecuteMultipleResponse();
//create a faulted Item
var item = new ExecuteMultipleResponseItem() {
    Faulted = true,
    //..can also add response.
}
//add faulted item to response to make it faulted as well
response.Responses.Add(item);
//response should now also be faulted.
response.Faulted.Should().BeTrue(); //using FluentAssertions

//...use response in test as needed
```